# Cannot connect to Gmail: Unable to create TCP socket: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: php, gmail-imap

Gmail IMAP `open` is giving the error:

> Cannot connect to Gmail: Unable to create TCP socket: Address family not supported by protocol.

Error is coming in Linux server. Is there any configuration missing?

Code is:

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $username, $password)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something related to IPV6 vs. IPV4.
My two cents is that the system is trying to use ipv6 and then not falling back to ipv4 on failure. You can try to use the IP address instead of the host name: try pinging imap.gmail.com and replace the host name with the IP (for me is 64.233.167.109).

By the way, I think that the correct host string to use for gmail imap is

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", $username, $password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an IP address instead of `imap.gmail.com` address does work and allow for a successful connection, however this hardly seems like a true long-term solution.